# AngularJS dashboard utilizing ng-include with their own controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to create a dashboard out of two partials with their own separate controllers.

I have no issue utilizing ng-include to achieve getting the templates loaded correctly, the issue I am running into is tying their own controllers into the dashboard so they operate as two separate modules on the same dashboard page.  Has anyone accomplished this task, or do I just need to have everything required of the sub-scopes copied into the main dashboard scope?

*EDIT*
I am still having some trouble wrapping my head around all of this.... so I created a plunker of my currentish config, trimmed down slightly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uM7liZ74EmuD2zPkotHN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-include`, write a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Something like:

```
app.directive('moduleOne', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'module-one.html',
    scope: {
      model: '=' // << two-way binding
    },
    link: function () {
      // post compile stuff
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
      // controller stuff
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.model.text = 'change in model one';
      }, 4000);
    }]
  };
});

app.directive('moduleTwo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'module-two.html',
    scope: {
      string: '@attr' // << one-way binding
    },
    link: function () {
      // post compile stuff
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
      // controller stuff
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.string = 'change in model two';
      }, 2000);
    }]
  };
});
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/MELkTcrllroHRY7zyh3H

---

**update**

Have a look at the `scope` property. I added two (of 3 possible) ways to interact with the parent-scope. For a better explanation have a look at the **Directive Definition Object** section from the [api-link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) above.

**update 2**

Unfortunately the plunker is not completey working for me, though from what I see, I can understand some of your problems. I think you're still doing way to much work in you the controllers. You should extract much of what you do there and put it into services.

Also the `$scope.newOrderBy` is really breaking the idea of angular. Replace that with a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.using_filters). Then having a lot of `$location.path` in the controller is, at least from my point of view, problematic. Have a look at [step 7](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) of the tutorial to get a hint of how this could be done better (e.g. `<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>`).

Then there is the routing inside both `contractors` and `companies` which does not make much sense, if you want to place those as widgets into a dashboard.

I understand that the above might not be much of help, though I'll try to add another plunker, to show some of the ideas mentioned.

**Update 3**

the promised [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CDFbsCECogbO507WMn6z) ...finally

**Update 4**

another [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNiGL1nbCI8y6is8tAAF) showing one way to resolve something for the active route, and injecting it into an included directive.

Comment: I have several deferreds in my resolve statements, how do you import those correctly?

Comment: @Brian There are some techniques you could employ. 1) [Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services) 2) the `scope` configuration. I'll try to add an example.

Comment: I had been basing my applications off of https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app as a jumping off point I liked how everything is structured and each is its own separate module contained for a set of actions.  The plunker doesn't work in its current configuration as it references an unbuilt portion of the code, but I wanted to show how things are structured currently.

Comment: @Brian I added a new plunker, hopefully it will help you somewhat. Note that I'm deliberately not using `ngResource` in the `CompaniesLoader`, though that could be easily changed in your code.

Comment: You could also easily extract the company-specfic code into it's own module. I didn't do so, just to have an easier setup for the example.

Comment: This looks awesome! I think I have a handle on how to implement it with my full code.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29245/discussion-between-brian-and-yoshi)

Comment: @Brian I read your new comment in the chat. Have a look at the new plunker, especially the `companiesDashboard2` directive.

Comment: Okay that's what I had gone with was utilizing the '=' parameter and still having my deffereds evaluate for the dashboard controller, I just didn't know if this was the best practice way of doing this.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Brian Best practices aside, I think it's problematic in another way. This way of coupling prevents the `companies-dashboard` directive from being used as a stand-alone component. Without the coupling you could place it everywhere in your app without worrying. With it, you'll always have to make sure it's supplied with the right data.

Comment: @Yoshi, offtopic, do you have screencasts or youtube? Because you should really do some!